# Creating/Writing/Reading CSV file in Golang

Tags: go

The following code should create a CSV file and write the employee data to it, then read it out in the terminal. The code will create the file and not print the contents in the terminal. If I take the last chunk of code out to print the contents, it will work as an independent program as long as the CSV file is present. Why does the code not work when written all as one?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "sort"
)

type Employee struct {
    Name   string
    Age    int
    Salary float64
}

func main() {
    employees := []Employee{
        {"Fred", 44, 56000.00},
        {"Amy", 25, 65000.00},
        {"Zack", 29, 20400.00},
        {"Jerry", 73, 120500.00},
    }

    sort.Slice(employees, func(i, j int) bool {
        return employees[i].Name < employees[j].Name
    })

    file, err := os.Create("employees.csv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    writer := csv.NewWriter(file)
    defer writer.Flush()

    header := []string{"Name", "Age", "Salary"}
    if err := writer.Write(header); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, employee := range employees {
        record := []string{employee.Name, fmt.Sprintf("%d", employee.Age), fmt.Sprintf("%.2f", employee.Salary)}
        if err := writer.Write(record); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }

    file, err = os.Open("employees.csv")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    records, err := reader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    for _, record := range records {
        fmt.Println(record)
    }
}
```

```
//This code will print the contents of the CSV correctly when ran separately
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("employees.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    reader.FieldsPerRecord = -1
    records, err := reader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error reading CSV data:", err)
        return
    }

    for _, record := range records {
        fmt.Println(record)
    }
}
```

The first program will create the CSV file with the expected cells, but instead of printing the contents to the terminal, the program completes.

Comment: The file content is in the CSV writer's in-memory buffer and is not flushed to the file until the main function returns.  Flush the CSV writer and close the file before reading the file.  https://go.dev/play/p/3PdtQ174hCD

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Flushing the CSV writer after the reader declaration solved my issue.